# Grouping by customer ID

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a huge table containing monthly entries for customers during 2016-2017. Some of the customers churn during this period and new customers are added. Each customer has a unique customer id.

I would like to group the customers by customer id. For each row, I want to find out the annual revenue in 2016 and 2017 and the information if they have churned during these years. In addition, I want to include some demographics. If there is now data entry for customer in December, they have churned during that year.

Table now:

```
customer_id month   revenue gender  dob  
c1          012016  40      F       1956  
c1          022016  50      F       1956  
...  
c1          122017  50      F       1956  
c2          032017  700     F       1967  
c3          012017  50      M       1989  
c3          022017  10      M       1989
```

The desired output:

```
customer_id rev2016 rev2016 churned2016 churned2017 gender dob  
c1          90      150     0           0           F      1956  
c2          0       700     0           1           F      1967  
c3          0       60      0           1           M      1989
```

I was thinking about using pandas groupby or pivot but don't know how to start. Any insights would be helpful.

Comment: Could you include your  own attempt in python.

Answer (score 0):

```
# convert month to str
df['month'] = df['month'].astype(str)
# list comprehension to split the year from month
df['year'] = [x[1:] if len(x) == 5 else x[2:] for x in df['month']]
# groupby year and unstack
df.groupby(['customer_id', 'year'])['revenue'].sum().unstack()

year         2016   2017
customer_id             
c1           90.0   50.0
c2            NaN  700.0
c3            NaN   60.0
```